# Get event after function complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where people can delete records;

```
<a href="/delete/1" class="confirm-action">Delete Record 1</a>
<a href="/delete/2" class="confirm-action">Delete Record 2</a>
<a href="/delete/3" class="confirm-action">Delete Record 3</a>
```

To ensure they are sure, I am using a "Are you sure" confirmation script ([Popconfirm](https://github.com/Ifnot/PopConfirm)) which gives a nice little popup confirmation.

```
$(".confirm-action").popConfirm();
```

If the user clicks cancel, nothing happens. If they click 'yes' - the link is processed and the record deleted. This is working as intended.

Now instead of following the link (when the user clicks 'yes'), I want to fire an ajax request:

```
$('.confirm-action').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
            // Ajax stuff here
      });
});
$(".confirm-action").popConfirm();
```

The problem is when I try this, the functions are fired in the correct order when expected, except the `event` is `null`, so the script fails.

How do I "`preventDefault()`" when the `event` is `null`, and/or manually get the `event` to prevent the link from being followed by the browser?

Edit: [JSFiddle showing the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/87UY3/)

Comment: yeah - I'm trying to getting the PopConfirm to work on JSfiddle - will post a link shortly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/87UY3/

Comment: This happens because the plugin you're using is horrible! I'm assuming it's [this one](https://github.com/Ifnot/PopConfirm/blob/master/jquery.popconfirm.js), and it uses jQuery's _data(events) to get the events, and then just evals them when you click OK, so in that context the event is indeed undefined, and short of rewriting the plugin there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Ok, thanks adeneo - do you know another plugin that does something similar?

Comment: Agreed with @adeneo - that plugin IS horrible. Look for one that has a convenient interface to deal with yes / no events. For example, $(".something").confirm({ "yes": function() { /* do stuff here */ } });

Comment: [**Bootbox**](http://bootboxjs.com/) seems to be popular for Boostrap.

Comment: Here's a small self-made alternative. It's a clumsy prototype, but gives confirmation without complicating things with modals: http://pp19dd.com/2012/03/confirm-dialog-without-a-dialog/

Comment: Actually you dont need to call `event.preventDefault();` if you are using this plugin. Event default is prevented by plugin itself https://github.com/Ifnot/PopConfirm/blob/master/jquery.popconfirm.js#L111 Saying that I still agree to adeneo. The plugin is awful.

Comment: Thanks Yury. Unfortunately once the 'yes' button is pressed, it then carries on with the original event, so I cant do my ajax call. But I've found another plugin that *seems* to be better and solves my problem: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Tavicu/bootstrap-confirmation/master/bootstrap-confirmation.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the plugin is horrible and plays with `_data(events)` IE plays with internal event management of jQuery.

If you aren't concerned about the UI, I would suggest you to go with normal `confirm()` as used in SO.

I've created this for you while typing this answer:

```
$.fn.nativeConfirm = function (options) {
    return this.click(function () {
        var bool = confirm(options.text);
        bool ? options.yes.call(this) : options.no.call(this);
    });
}
```

Example:

```
$('a').nativeConfirm({
    yes: function(){
      alert('yes');
    },
    no:function(){
      alert('no');
    },
    text: 'Seriously?'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I found another plugin that *seems* to be better than my original one, and solves my problem: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Tavicu/bootstrap-confirmation/master/bootstrap-confirmation.js - but if that causes my issues I'll revert to this. Appreciate your help!

Comment: glad to have helped you ;)